# Вывод TV полей в универсальный шаблон и обращение к нужному TV для одной из страниц

Tags: modx, revo

Есть 6 страниц, которые получают содержимое из универсального шаблона.
У этих страниц есть "Табы", для которых созданы TV поля.
Для вывода табов, TV поля размещаются в чанках, а шаблон выводит чанки на главную страницу.
Проблема в том, что при стандартном выводе pdoResources нужно указывать ресурс, который разный у каждой страницы. Как сделать так, чтобы каждая страница тянула именно свои TV поля, видя себя же ресурсом, а не одного? Проще говоря, что-то вида [!pdoResources? resources='[[+id]](я и есть ресурс)' tpl='name_tpl' ...]
Чтобы было понятнее, родитель будет один, по этому нужно просто как-то сказать странице, или же правильнее сказать pdoreources'у, чтобы он брал ID текущей страницы и ставил в ID ресурса

&showlog='1' выводит:

```
0.0000520: pdoTools loaded
0.0000119: xPDO query object created
0.0000930: Added selection of modResource: `id`, `type`, `contentType`, `pagetitle`, `longtitle`, `description`, `alias`, `alias_visible`, `link_attributes`, `published`, `pub_date`, `unpub_date`, `parent`, `isfolder`, `introtext`, `richtext`, `template`, `menuindex`, `searchable`, `cacheable`, `createdby`, `createdon`, `editedby`, `editedon`, `deleted`, `deletedon`, `deletedby`, `publishedon`, `publishedby`, `menutitle`, `donthit`, `privateweb`, `privatemgr`, `content_dispo`, `hidemenu`, `class_key`, `context_key`, `content_type`, `uri`, `uri_override`, `hide_children_in_tree`, `show_in_tree`, `properties`
0.0002859: Processed additional conditions
0.0003870: Added where condition: modResource.parent:IN(4), modResource.published=1, modResource.deleted=0
0.0000460: Sorted by modResource.publishedon, DESC
0.0000029: Limited to 10, offset 0
0.0001361: SQL prepared "SELECT `modResource`.`id`, `modResource`.`type`, `modResource`.`contentType`, `modResource`.`pagetitle`, `modResource`.`longtitle`, `modResource`.`description`, `modResource`.`alias`, `modResource`.`alias_visible`, `modResource`.`link_attributes`, `modResource`.`published`, `modResource`.`pub_date`, `modResource`.`unpub_date`, `modResource`.`parent`, `modResource`.`isfolder`, `modResource`.`introtext`, `modResource`.`richtext`, `modResource`.`template`, `modResource`.`menuindex`, `modResource`.`searchable`, `modResource`.`cacheable`, `modResource`.`createdby`, `modResource`.`createdon`, `modResource`.`editedby`, `modResource`.`editedon`, `modResource`.`deleted`, `modResource`.`deletedon`, `modResource`.`deletedby`, `modResource`.`publishedon`, `modResource`.`publishedby`, `modResource`.`menutitle`, `modResource`.`donthit`, `modResource`.`privateweb`, `modResource`.`privatemgr`, `modResource`.`content_dispo`, `modResource`.`hidemenu`, `modResource`.`class_key`, `modResource`.`context_key`, `modResource`.`content_type`, `modResource`.`uri`, `modResource`.`uri_override`, `modResource`.`hide_children_in_tree`, `modResource`.`show_in_tree`, `modResource`.`properties` FROM `modx_site_content` AS `modResource` WHERE  ( `modResource`.`parent` IN (4) AND `modResource`.`published` = 1 AND `modResource`.`deleted` = 0 )  ORDER BY modResource.publishedon DESC LIMIT 10 "
0.0002818: SQL executed
0.0000060: Rows fetched
0.0000079: Returning processed chunks
0.0010910: Total time
4 194 304: Memory usage
```

В ЛС готов показать структуру, если что-то не понятно, но вроде как всё максимально подробно объяснил

pdoResources сейчас:

```
[[pdoResources? &resources=`4` &parents=`3` &depth=`1` &tpl =`Tab Benefits` &includeTVs=`Content advantages` ]]
```

Структура:
(изображение удалено)

Если сделать вывод так:

```
[[pdoResources? &parents=`[[+id]]` &tpl =`Tab Benefits` &includeTVs=`Content advantages` ]]
```

То выводятся TV поля со всех страниц, т.е. их становится 6 (изображение удалено)

Родитель тут "Каталог товаров", и TV поля нужны с ресурсов лежащих внутри этого каталога. По этому я и писал изначально что мне надо именно к ресурсу обратиться как к самому себе

Comment: если разные страницы имеют разные табы или их количество, то просто вызывайте в шаблоне [!pdoResources? &parents='[[*id]] - он будет собирать все дочерние страницы от главной, на другой главной он будет собирать ее дочерние

Comment: Не вызывает вообще таким образом ничего, без указания resources он просто отказывается работать

Comment: добавьте параметр &showLog=1 что выводит? pdoResources должен работать и без resources

Comment: Добавил кусок кода который выводится выше в сам вопрос

Comment: я не вижу в логе tv полей, вы их добавляете параметром `&includeTVs=tv_поля`? и дочерние ресурсы опубликованы? и ваши табы точно дочерние ресурсы от страницы (4)? лучше наверно хотя бы примерно структуру показать, дерево ваших страниц, можете сделать тестовые но с тойже структурой, и ваш вызов pdoResources скорее всего там не все параметры указываете

Comment: Дописал информацию в вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116933/discussion-between-tunker-and-alexandr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdoresources` нужен если вы с других своих ресурсов берете что-то, объединяете, фильтруете, возможно делаете постраничную пагинацию. А тут у вас есть страницы которые должны вывести свои же поля в определенном виде (по шаблону).

Для этого вам необходимо указать необходимый шаблон для ваших страниц, и в шаблоне (или чанке вызываемом из этого шаблона) указать `tv-поля` со * например `[[*image-url]]`